# Move data with compression

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, compression, zip, 7-zip

I'm using win 7.I have disk ~2Tb which one I want to format so I need to move data from it to other disk, but the problem is that I have not another 2Tb disk and I think I can compress data(on the fly) when I move it to other disks.

Which tools are suitable for this?
At start I think about .zip or 7zip but what limitations of size of archive it have? maybe there is better compression scheme?
How it will work? For example I have 12 Gb file and want to copy it to 5 Gb disk, so I don't want it to start to work and then tell me that there is no enough space, but I want to check before run how much Gb of storage needed(depending on my data and compression scheme).

Comment: How much data is on the disk you want to format? How much data are you trying to save? How big is the "spare" disk that you have where you want to store the data while formatting?

Comment: There is no such thing as a predictable compression ratio. Deal with it.

Comment: @yoshm I want to format full disk. The question is that I have X Gb of data I want to know how large "spare" disk I need to backup it.

Comment: @DanielB why not? What if algorithm pass through data and calc size of resulting archive?If it needed for "dictionary"(or something) it may use some "buffer" on disk which size is previously predifined and deleted after calculation.

Comment: Because this is how compression works. You cannot tell the size until you go through the file and try to compress it.

Comment: It also depends on the kind of data you want to compress. If it's all mpeg, jpeg, mp3, you won't gain anything from compression.

Comment: Sure, you could discard all compressed data and only keep the size. This would, however, still require the algorithm to process *all* data.

Comment: @DanielB what algorithm? how I can test it?

Comment: If you know the nature of the data you can guesstimate the compression. As others have noted, some data won't compress at all (e.g., jpg, mp3, etc.) since it's already compressed while other data (e.g., text files) can compress up to 90% (or more). For a perfect prediction, it is true - you (or rather some program) must process all the data.  What is your goal? To figure out how big a spare disk you must buy to save your data during formatting? I have a better suggestion: buy another 2TB drive and let it be your backup drive moving forward, too (not just while you format your drive).

Comment: The compression algorithm. It would have to run to completion to tell the result size—which, naturally, takes ages. And if it were to fit, you'd have to run it again. This is only a solution when your storage is over 2 times slower than the compression. You know, 56K modem speed and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You **can`t** predict the compression size. The only chance I see is to try this:

```
7z a -t7z -mx9 -o f:\outputDirectory e:\inputDirectory
```

Compress all the files, and just wait if its finishes or abort due to the lack of spaaace.

Note that 7z.exe needs to be in your [*path*](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284361#284361) for this command. Alternativly you can specify the full path to the 7z.exe

```
C:\Programs\7-Zip\7z a -t7z -mx9 -o f:\outputDirectory e:\inputDirectory
```